# Does memory allocated to tmpfs free itself when needed by an application?

Tags: linux, centos, tmpfs

I have 8GB of RAM and 4GB is dedicated to the tmpfs on /dev/shm.

There's nothing actually in /dev/shm, so I'm wondering, is this memory still available for applications to use?

If I needed to use 7GB in an application (which I do) would the tmpfs give up part of its allocated memory for this, or would I end up using swap after 4GB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `Documentation/filesystems/tmpfs.txt`:

> tmpfs ... grows and
>   shrinks to accommodate the files it contains and is able to swap
>   unneeded pages out to swap space.

So unless you needed all 4GB of data stored in `tmpfs` at once, you would get as much RAM for your applications as feasible.